Are there rules for gender of durations?
When trying to write a program to display durations in German language, I noticed a problem that I did not notice before:
Words for German durations have different genders, and I wonder whether there is a rule to explain that.
For example

Sekunde: female
Minute: female
Stunde: female
Tag: male
Monat: male
Jahr: neutral

So for example one can say

Bis zu meinem Urlaub sind es 2 Tage und 7 Stunden

or

In 2 Taqen und 7 Stunden habe ich Urlaub

So for my program the neutral and female variants are nice as the program just has to remove the last character (n) to make singular, but obviously for the male variant it's either the last (e) or the last two characters (en).
Essentially I wonder whether there exist rules to determine the gender of those duration words.

To continue your list: "die Dekade", "das Jahrhundert" .....

Simple rule: There are no rules.
Wall clock and calendar durations are as mentioned in your list. Other (more obscure) time durations' genders also don't follow any specific rules like

der Augenblick
der Moment
das Jahrzehnt
das Quartal
....

If you only use wall clock and calendar durations, a small table should be simple enough to implement.

I also thought so, but not knowing a rule does not mean there doesn't exist one (unless there is a rule saying that there is no rule).

Another idea that came into my mind: "die Zeit" is feminine, but "Der Kalender" is masculine, and could it be due to the fact that the calendar came from the Romans (Julian/Gregorian)? I'm unsure what's the gender there.

calendarium as the origin of Kalender is a neuter in Latin. That didn't make it into German.

There are a few rules for a few classes of nouns, like diminutives are always neuter (das Häuschen = the little house, das Mädchen = the girl (literal: the little maiden), das Sackerl = the little bag, ...), nominalized adjectives ending in -heit or -keit are always feminine (die Schönheit = the beauty, die Eitelkeit = the vanity, ...)
But nouns naming temporal entities are not such a class.
Generally spoken: It is an exception when a noun belongs to a class with a gender that is valid for all members of the class. The norm is, that you have to learn the gender of each noun separately, like we native speakers did when we learned our language as children.
btw.: You forgot these

die Woche, die Wochen (feminine)
das Quartal, die Quartale (neuter)
die Olympiade, die Olympiaden (feminine)
das Jahrzehnt, die Jahrzehnte (neuter)
die Dekade, die Dekaden (feminine)
das Jahrhundert, die Jahrhunderte (neuter)
das Jahrtausend, die Jahrtausende (neuter)

German also has some multi-gender nouns. I estimate that there are approximately 100 German nouns that have two genders, and less than 5 that can be used with all three genders. Monat is one of the nouns that was two genders. The neuter form is preferred in Austria and Bavaria, the masculine form in all other regions, but both forms are correct everywhere:

das Monat, die Monate (neuter)
der Monat, die Monate (masculine)


Addendum (Reaktion auf Kommentare)
In Kommentaren wurde behauptet, dass die sächliche Form das Monat absolut unüblich sei. Das mag vielleicht für Deutschland stimmen, für Österreich ist diese kategorische Behauptung jedoch falsch. Ich selbst benutze in der Alltagssprache ausschließlich die sächliche Form (das Monat), die in Wiktionary und Wikipedia mit dem Hinweis auf die Beschränkung auf Österreich auch klar belegt ist. Die männliche Form (der Monat) erscheint mir unnatürlich.
Hier sind weitere Belege aus dem Internet:

das Monat des Schulsports - Eine offizielle Seite der Bildungsdirektion des Landes Niederösterreich
Abrechnung für das Monat ... - Infoportal für Ärztinnen und Ärtze mit Sitz in Linz (Bundesland Oberösterreich)
Das Monat ... - Website der Wirtschaftskammer (Standorte und Online-Redaktionen in allen österreichischen Bundesländern)
finanziell durch das Monat kommen - Rede eines Parlamentariers im österreichischen Parlament
Entschuldigung für das Monat ... - Formular, bereitgestellt von der Fachschule für Sozialberufe Stockerau (liegt in Niederösterreich)
das Monat des zweiten Datums - Beschreibung einer Berechnungsformel auf der Website der österreichischen Nationalbank (Sitz in Wien)
Gibt das Monat aus - Tutorial zur Programmiersprache C# eines IT-Unternehmens mit Sitz in Linz (Oberösterreich)
für das Monat September 2023 - Website eines kleinen privaten Radiosenders (aus Niederösterreich)
das Monat der Maiandachten - Website eines privaten Fernsehsenders aus dem Salzkammergut (Region im Dreiländereck Salzburg, Oberösterreich, Steiermark)
das Monat der Ernte - Website einer Imkervereinigung aus Wien
Sobald Sie zufrieden sind, können Sie das Monat abschließen. - Beschreibung einer Lohnverrechnungs-Software auf der Website des Herstellers mit Sitz in Wien


Das Monat ist absolut unüblich und kennt keines meiner Wörterbücher, und online bspw auch nicht dwds. Thus not correct... at least not in my books

Ich habe den Ausdruck "das Monat" schon gehört. Im österreichischen Wörterbuch lässt er sich aber nicht finden. Dort gibt es nur "der Monat".

@planetmaker: Beachte mein der Antwort hinzugefügtes Addendum.

There are a lot more "rules for nouns", as every linguist can tell you: there are the "s-stems" (masculine), the "m-stems" (neutral), the abstractae (feminine) and so on.

But the names of the individual months themselves are all masculine.

There is no rule. A program that displays these kinds of durations in German needs to store singular and plural form (gender only if it needs to display things like "ein Tag" vs. "eine Stunde", you can omit it if you display "1 Tag", "1 Stunde") of each word that might occur. If it might be displayed in a context like "vor einem Tag", it also needs to store dative plural (vor zwei Tagen, aber es hat zwei Tage gedauert).
